# jQuery Tablesorter Static Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, tablesorter

I've been struggling to find an answer to this question. That is, how would I have a static row that doesn't sort or move up and down? The reason for this is to have repeated headers in a very large table. The multiple headers Would anyone be able to help?
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

```
$("#dataTable").tablesorter({
                sortList: [[0, 0], [1, 0]],
                widgets: ['zebra', 'rowHover'],
                widgetZebra: { css: ["even", "odd"] },
                widgetRowHover: { css: 'rowhover' }
            });

..
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Row 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Row 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Static Row
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Row 3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I realise that this is ~4 months old now, but I ran into a similar problem and created a widget for Tablesorter that allows you to mark any rows as static. Take a look if you're still interested: http://asciisoup.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/static-rows-widget-for-jquery-tablesorter/

Comment: @Nils: you should add your comment as an answer, since it is a great solution (helped me).

Answer (score 4):

I was asked by @patmortech to add my comment above as an answer. So here is my comment verbatim.

I realise that this is ~4 months old now, but I ran into a similar problem and created a widget for Tablesorter that allows you to mark any rows as static. Take a look if you're still interested: http://asciisoup.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/static-rows-widget-for-jquery-tablesorter/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to break this table into 2 tables and adjust the columns widths **if possible**. Especially if you are not grouping rows.